# Java Recursion issue Maze

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java and am trying to solve mazes with recursion. I have added part of the code below. I have a 2D array that contains the "field". Walls are 1, start coordinate is given and end coordinate aswell.

I have one questions;

I want to erase the placement of the Path whenever it cannot continue & end hasn't been reached. How do I do this?

- I have tried adding booleans for it
- at the end of the recursion adding an maze[x][y] = '0' (empty)

but I can't figure it out yet, perhaps I did above wrong.

PS: I have searched on the forum , read alot about recursion and also how others tackled their problems but I couldn't figure out how to fix this little bit of code.

-P stands for Path
- width & height are from the 2D array, 
-I start off with starting navigate(xstart,ystart) (thats why I needed to try new positions whenever it finds B (beginning)

`navigate(int x, int y) {`

```
    if (x < 0 || x > width - 1 || y < 0 || y > height - 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (maze[x][y] == '1') {
        return;
    }
    if (maze[x][y] == 'E') {
        maze[x][y] = 'P';
    }

    if (maze[x][y] == 'P') {
        return;
    }
    if (maze[x][y] == '0') {
        maze[x][y] = 'P';
        return;
    }
    if (maze[x][y] == 'B') {
        maze[x][y] = 'P';
        navigate(x + 1, y);
        navigate(x, y + 1);
        navigate(x - 1, y);
        navigate(x, y - 1);
        return;
    }
    maze[x][y] = 'P';
    navigate(x + 1, y);
    navigate(x, y + 1);
    navigate(x - 1, y);
    navigate(x, y - 1);
}
```

Going to put down the things I did to make it work. It has been quite a while though but anyone reading it might find it helpfull.

I just created arrays and an array of those arrays. Where each path was stored, just picked a max number but in an ideal situation you should give it length rows * columns (as that is the max length). You create one after an end has been found.

Comment: I think you will get better answer if you add a sample test case for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an ArrayList containing the locations that the particular recursion has, then once you hit 'O' go through the ArrayList and make every location on it an 'F' for final path. Then, at the end of the method, clear all 'P's (possibly by going through every element of the 2D array) At the end, you have one or more paths denoted by F that lead you to the end.

I'm assuming 'O' is your ending location.

Comment: If someone's idea worked, please accept their answer so that the question does not remain in unanswered. Or, if it didn't, please tell them

Answer (score 0):

The only markers you need are:

```
1 - wall
0 - empty (can use for path)
P - path
```

Now, let's start navigating at the start point:

```
navigate(xstart, ystart);
```

How do we navigate?

```
navigate(int x, int y) {

    // Are we there yet?
    if (x == xend && y == yend) {
        // Yay! We're here! And our path is marked with P's
        // However, you're many levels inside the recursion. How to break out?
        // Easiest way - throw an exception, and catch in the original caller
    }

    // Don't step where you're not supposed to
    if (x < 0 || x > width - 1 || y < 0 || y > height - 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (maze[x][y] == '1' || maze[x][y] == 'p') {
        return;
    }

    // OK, we can step through here. Let's mark this place as path
    maze[x][y] = 'P';

    // Now, let's try continuing to neighboring squares
    navigate(x + 1, y);
    navigate(x, y + 1);
    navigate(x - 1, y);
    navigate(x, y - 1);

    // If we're still here, guess this square is not on the path - remove it
    maze[x][y] = '0';
}
```

*(warning: Haven't tested the code, and I'm a C# programmer - but it should be the same)*

Fun tests:

- What happens if you change the order of the recursive `navigate()` calls?
- What if there are only few walls? How would this algorithm use the space?

Recursion is fun! And you can get an actual Sack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking the exact same thing as what you posted although it doesn't do the trick for some reason :/ I think I have to add, as Rufus stated some extra arrays to "save" the passed/checked coordinates.